# Why do I see symbol linking error messages when the symbols are present?

Tags: dll

I have two object files, one with a couple of symbols defined and one in which those symbols are undefined:

```
nm ./src/freertos/freertos.o |grep pvPortMalloc
000000000000d045 T pvPortMalloc
```

...and...

```
nm ./src/clib/new_delete.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U _Z12pvPortMalloci
                 U _Z9vPortFreePv
0000000000000019 T _ZdlPv
0000000000000000 T _Znwm
```

When I attempt to link them together, I see this:

```
ld ./src/clib/new_delete.o ./src/freertos/freertos.o 
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
ld: ./src/clib/new_delete.o: in function `operator new(unsigned long)':
new_delete.cc:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc(int)'
ld: ./src/clib/new_delete.o: in function `operator delete(void*)':
new_delete.cc:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `vPortFree(void*)'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your `nm` listings do not show there is any undefined symbol reported in `./src/clib/new_delete.o`
that is defined in `./src/freertos/freertos.o`.

There is a similarity between the
symbol `pvPortMalloc` defined in `./src/freertos/freertos.o` and the undefined
symbol `_Z12pvPortMalloci` in `./src/clib/new_delete.o` which I guess leads you to suppose that they are
the same, but the linker does not equate symbols on the basis of any similarity short of identity.

The symbol `_Z12pvPortMalloci` is the C++ [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of:

```
$ c++filt _Z12pvPortMalloci
pvPortMalloc(int)
```

showing that `./src/clib/new_delete.o` was compiled with a C++ compiler. `./src/freertos/freertos.o`,
on the other hand, was compiled with a C compiler, which does not do name-mangling.

If you want to tell your C++ compiler that the external name `pvPortMalloc` in
your source code is to have C linkage language, and therefore not to mangle it,
you must declare it [`extern "C"`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

**Wrong**

```
$ cat wrong.cpp
extern void * pvPortMalloc(int);

int main()
{
    return pvPortMalloc(42) != nullptr;
}

$ g++ -Wall -c wrong.cpp
$ nm wrong.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U _Z12pvPortMalloci
```

**Right**

```
$ cat right.cpp 

extern "C" {
    void * pvPortMalloc(int);
    // And any more...
}

int main()
{
    return pvPortMalloc(42) != nullptr;
}

$ g++ -Wall -c right.cpp
$ nm right.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U pvPortMalloc
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  I have to compile the code with g++ because some of it is C++, so this was helpful info....

Comment: @JonTaylor Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here is [our way of saying "Thanks"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
Should you need to consume an entire header file of C declarations in a C++
translation unit, enclose the `#include <c_header.h>` within `extern "C" {...}`
(although many C library header files now are already internally prepared
for C++ consumption).